# CTRL+R stops working until reboot 2.82

Tags: loop

Just randomly my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> *Loop-Cut* shortcut stops working in Blender 2.82 and won't work again until I reboot my PC.

Has anyone else seen that?

Comment: Should at least work when opening up a new instance of blender (without a reboot). Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Good call I've not checked the console will check that next time, but even a fresh restart of blender doesn't fix it, requires reboot. Weird.

Comment: Huh, I guess it's either your graphics card or the keyboard. How about executing the operator via F3 -> "Loop Cut and..."?

Comment: It works if I select loop cut from the toolbar, it's just the shortcut that stops working randomly.